# python many-to many relationship how to connect two tables into a third one

Tags: python, sql, many-to-many, relationships

SO I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship between author and books.  I have my author table as author_id, author_first,author_last. For my books table i have book_id, and book_title. My third table I have wrote which has book_id and author_id.  I'm working on my python code and I have two classes a main and a database. For my b_command I'm trying to get my results to be like this:
Enter a book title: I like books
Enter an Author ID:1
Enter an Author ID: 2
But I can't seem to think how to add the author id in there.
Here is my code for my main method:

```
import pymysql
from project2database import *

db = database("project2")

done = False

def dashes(size=80,char='-'):
    print(char*size)

def commands():
    print("Commands are a(add an author), la(list the authors), b(enter a book with the author id), lb(list of books), q(quit)")

def a_command():
    #done = False
    print("Enter the name for an author. An empty first name ends the input")
    while not done:
        first= input("Enter the first name for an author: ")
        first = first.strip()
        if first == "":
            done = True
        else:
            last = input("Enter the last name for an author: ")
            last = last.strip()
            db.add_author(first,last)

def la_command():
    db.print_author()

def b_command():
    done = False
    print("Enter the name for a book and the Author id: ")
    while not done:
        title = input("Enter a book title: ")
        title = title.strip()
        if title=="":
            done = True
        else:
            db.add_book(title)





stop = False
commands()
while not stop:
    command = input("Enter your command --> ")
    command = command.strip().lower()
    if command == 'a':
        a_command()
    elif command == 'la':
        la_command()
    elif command == 'b':
        b_command()
    elif command == 'q':
        stop = True
    elif command == "":
        pass
    else:
```

Here is my code for my database:

import pymysql
import sys

class database:

```
con = ""
name = ""
dbname = ""
last=0

def __init__(self,db_name): ## constructor
    try:
        self.con= pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db=db_name)
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        print("Database Error [{:d}]: {:s}".format(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        sys.exit(0)
    self.dbname = db_name

def close(self):   
    self.con.close()

def add_author(self,first,last):
    query = "insert into author(author_first,author_last) values ('{:s}','{:s}')".format(first,last)
    try:
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        self.last = cur.lastrowid
        self.con.commit()
        #print(query)
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        print("Database Error[{:d}]: {:s}".format(e.args[0], e.args[1]))

def print_author(self):
    print("The authors are: ")
    query = """
     select author_id,author_first,author_last from author
    """
    cur = self.con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    row = cur.fetchone()

    while row is not None:
        print("{:d}->{:s},{:s}".format(row[0],row[1],row[2]))
        row = cur.fetchone()

def add_book(self,title)
    query = "insert into books(book_title) values ('{:s}')".format(title)
    try:
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        self.last = cur.lastrowid
        self.con.commit()
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        print("Database Error[{{:d}]: {:s}".format(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
```

Comment: what is the DDL statement for your author table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `author` (
  `author_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_first` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `author_last` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`author_id`),
  KEY `author_id` (`author_id`),
  KEY `author_id_2` (`author_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that ID fields in your tables are set as `AUTO INCREMENT` or `IDENTITY`.

This means that every time you insert a new record, database will assign incremented value (since the previous insert) to the ID field.

You should not set ID value yourself, let RDBMS do it for you.

Comment: I did that but Im not sure how to associate the book with the author in the end

Comment: You need to insert book and author IDs in your "third" table that links authors to books.

Comment: I have that but I dont how to connect the to.  Like i have in my example I'm trying to ask for the book title and then ask for all the others that are associated with that book and be able to print that out

Comment: You should ask for book_id, not title.

Comment: I am I'm trying to have my results be something similiar like
Enter a book title: 
Enter a author id:
Enter a author id:
And then connect the too in the end but I'm not sure how to get the ids into the wrote table